# jQuery trigger event when form field is validated

Tags: jquery, formvalidation-plugin, formvalidation.io

I'm trying to trigger a function to update the CSS of a progress bar...

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" role="progressbar"></div>
</div>
```

But only after a field has been validated by the formValidation plugin (formvalidation.io)

```
$('form').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    fields: { ... }
});
```

When a field is validated, formValidation adds the `has-success` class to the field. I have created a function to count how many fields have this class, calculate a percentage width for the progress bar and update the CSS

```
$('.form-control').on('change keydown', function(){
    var fields = 9;
    var completedFields = $('.has-success').length;
    var percent = (completedFields / fields) * 100;
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', percent + '%');
});
```

The problem is, this only triggers after the *second* character is added into a text field or after a select is changed twice. I presume this is because the function fires before the `has-success` class has been added.

Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: use keypress instead of keydown

Answer (score 1):

You could listen to the error and success event after validation to trigger an update of the progress bar.

See: http://formvalidation.io/settings/#event-form

```
.on('err.form.fv', function(e) {
  // The e parameter is same as one
  // in the prevalidate.form.fv event above

  updateProgressBar();
})

.on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
  // The e parameter is same as one
  // in the prevalidate.form.fv event above

  updateProgressBar();
})
```

PS: Why don't you use the [`getInvalidFields()`](http://formvalidation.io/api/#get-invalid-fields) method the plugin offers to count the number of invalid fields?